# Lower and upper density of iterations of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory

For $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we define the lower and upper density by if $$\text{lowd}(A)=\text{lim inf}_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}, \text{upd}(A)=\text{lim sup}_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}.$$

Given $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we set $A+B = \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$. For $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ we define inductively:

- $1\ast A = A$;
- $(n+1) \ast A = (n\ast A)+A$.

Is there $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ with

1. $\text{lowd}(n*A) = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$;
2. there is $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{upd}(m*A) > 0$.

Comment: Set $a_{k}=2^{2^k}$ and  $A= \bigcup_k [a_k, 2 a_k ]$ (where an interval of integers is meant).

The upper density of $A$ is at least $1/2$.
 
Yet $|A\cap [1, a_k - 1] | \le 2a_{k-1}$ and so $|(n \ast A)\cap [1, a_k-1] | \le (2a_{k-1})^n$.

Since $\frac{a_{k-1}^n}{a_k-1}$ tends to $0$ for every fixed $n$ the lower density of $n \ast A$ is $0$.

Comment: As written this question is not on-topic on math.SE.